# How can I see the differences in a deeply nested object during testing?

Tags: node.js, tdd, mocha.js, assert

I am using Mocha and the tdd UI and `assert`. I wish to compare a deeply nested object in my tests.

```
var actual = {'foo': {'bar': 'baz'}}
var expected = {'foo': {'bar': 'boom'}}
assert.deepEqual(actual, expected)
```

The error I get back is:

```
AssertionError: {"foo":{"bar":"baz"}} deepEqual {"foo":{"bar":"boom"}}
```

What I would like is a diff - eg, `boom` highlighted in red so I can see that's causing the problem. Particularly since my object is a lot larger than this example. **How can I see the specific differences in a deeply nested object?**

Answer (score 0):

Serializing the object and comparing the string works:

```
var assertDeepEqual = function(actual, expected){
    assert.deepEqual(JSON.stringify(actual, null, 2), JSON.stringify(expected, null, 2))
}
```

This will show where the objects begin to differ.